# How to print a countdown from a given number including the negative copies from the user in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, countdown

I have to build a predicate called `count(X,L)` which  prints a countdown like

```
?- count(3,L).
L = [3,-3,2,-2,1,-1,0].    % expected result
```

I came up with this

```
countdown(X,[X|Z]) :-
   X > 0,
   Y is X-1,
   countdown(Y,Z).
countdown(0,[0]).
```

But I dont know how to get the negative copies?? Any help??
Thanks!

Comment: You can change your first clause` to countdown(X, [X,W|Z]):- X>0, W is -X, Y is X-1, countdown(Y,Z).` though I don't like how it "reads" (i.e. it will only work right in your intended way count(Number, List).

Comment: got it!! countdown(X, [X,-X|Z]):-
  X > 0,
 
  Y is X-1,
  countdown(Y, Z).
countdown(0, [0]).

Comment: @Jason: No! Please note that in `X = 1, L = [X,-X]` the `L` **not** the list `[1,-1]` but rather `[1,- (1)]`! You need to write rather `countdown(X,[X,Xneg|Z]) :- X > 0, Xneg is -X, ...`